# How to constantly monitor xrandr and automatically respond to a physical change in a multi monitor setup?

Tags: python, linux, bash, xrandr

I'm using a laptop with a mint linux and I use a multimonitor setup. I'll show my current xrandr output for reference at the end of the question.

I change my physical monitor setup several times a day. I unplug one or both external monitors and plug then in again later.

My current window manager - xfce - is not very good at responding to these changes. At the moment, when there is a change in the physical setup, I have to manually execute some prepared xrandr command so that xfce can adapt to the new monitor setup. This is one of the several prepared xrandr commands:

`xrandr --output DP1-1 --primary --right-of eDP1 --output DP1-2 --right-of DP1-1`

I don't want to do this manually anymore. I have several ideas to automatically react to a change in the physical monitor setup. This is the basic idea:

1. Monitor xrandr with a script in the background.
2. Save the current state of my monitor setup to a file (or keep it in memory)
3. If there is a change to the previous state, execute the appropriate xrandr command to respond to the change.

I see several options to do that:

1. Crob job every second: this is probably not a good idea because cron does not seem to be designed to execute commands every second - according to my research.
2. Prepare a bash script which is in an infinite loop and sleeps for one second at the end of the infinite loop.
3. Start a python script on startup, handle the logic of the monitor setup in this python script, put the python script into an endless loop and use time.sleep(1) at the end of the infinite loop. My idea to use python is simple: I'm a fair pyhton developer, but I'm poor when it comes to bash. Therefore, I feel much more confident working with python than with bash.
4. The linux kernel emits a signal, if there is a change in the monitor setup, and executes a script upon emitting this signal.

I have several questions:

1. If I use option 3: will the excuted python script be using a python interpreter within its own system process? Meaning: will this script block other python script with its sleep instruction if these other scripts share the same interpreter instance? I would like to use this monitor check script to run in the background and in its own process, so that other python scripts are unaffected.
2. If I use option 4: do those signals exist? How can I use them and how can I have them trigger a script, be it a bash script or a python script?

Thank you so much for your support!

Have a nice day.

xrandr output for reference:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5520 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 280mm x 160mm
   1920x1080     60.03*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00    59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1-1 connected primary 1680x1050+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 470mm x 300mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP1-2 connected 1920x1080+3600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: For your first question the answer should be easy to find out. Can you launch 2 interactive python sessions simultaneously? Can you `time.sleep(30)` in one and continue working in the other? You get your answer, I think.

Comment: You could go the "lazy" way.  Build a script that runs the appropriate `xrandr` command.  This script assumes something changed, and uses some logic to call the right one.  Then setup an alias or a desktop icon to launch it.  You know when you modify your monitor hardware, double cliking an icon to apply the change is not too bad...?

Comment: The second question is much more complex. When you (un)plug hardware peripherals, usually, interrupts are fired such that the kernel can react properly (load driver modules, attach a driver to the peripheral...) So, yes, there is probably a way to do what you want here. But patching your OS and implementing a bridge with Xfce is probably much more difficult than your python-based solution.

Comment: .1 **Avoid loop** whenever possible!!! .2 Use `monitor` tools: you could try: `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` or `journalctl -xf` or `dbus-monitor`... .3 Use *`FD`* awaiting for input (= event) instead of pooling `xrandr` in a *loop*.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/a-tool-for-automatically-applying-randr-configuration-when-external-display-is-p